# PhantomJS Issue with Loading Webpage: "Connection closed"'

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, connection

I'm working with PhantomJS and everything that I've done  works fine, but I don't know what happened bit time ago. The URL doesn't open in PhantomJS. The URL is [domain](https://www.procuraduria.gov.co/CertWEB/Certificado.aspx?tpo=1) and  the code is as follows:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),fs = require('fs'), args=require('system').args;
// var url = 'http://fotogena.co';
var url = 'https://www.procuraduria.gov.co/CertWEB/Certificado.aspx?tpo=1';
page.viewportSize = { width: 400, height: 400 };
page.open(url, function (status) {
    if(status==='success'){
        setTimeout(loadScripts, 1500)
    }else
        console.log(
                "Error opening url \"" + page.reason_url
                + "\": " + page.reason
            );
});

page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
    console.error('-----',resourceError.url + ': ' + resourceError.errorString, 'faber acá toy');
    phantom.exit(1);
};

function loadScripts(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        page.render('./probandoAntecedentes.jpg')
        phantom.exit(1);
    },1000)
}
```

The console displays the following:

```
https://www.procuraduria.gov.co/CertWEB/Certificado.aspx?tpo=1: Connection closed
```

I searched for possible solutions and put `--ssl-protocol=any` and other options, but they didn't work.

I'm using PhantomJS 2.1.1